# Cypress run stuck in infinite loading in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress

I'm trying to start the Cypress tests into Jenkins (shared Jenkins, no Jenkins server on my PC) and I'm getting stuck into an infinite load spinner after a cypress command is ran. I'm installing dependencies and running the tests inside the docker image "cypress/included:4.10.0".

If i write "cypress --version" is shows the version, but when I'm running "cypress run --browser chrome --headless" or other command with "cypress run" the loading spinner shows and nothing happens.

Checked the folders and the project is there, successfully cloned.

Locally, in my IDE, same commands are working as expected.

Is a configuration problem or docker?

Thank you!